# How to separate integer value from a string?

Tags: javascript

I have a string that contains alphabets and integer like banana12,apple123, i wanted to  separate integer value from a string. I have used split() function its working perfectly for single digit number ( orange1 ) but for double digit number it is returning only single digit.

```
 myString = banana12;
    var splits = myString.split(/(\d)/);
    var prodName = splits[0];
    var prodId = splits[1];
```

the prodId should be 12 but its returning only 1 as result.

Comment: what if string is something like "banana12with34" ..? what should be the output..?

Comment: Your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370263/separate-integers-and-text-in-a-string

Comment: Use `/(\d+)/` instead!

Comment: @Bergi I believe `split` itself is a bad choice here, what do you think?

Comment: @thefourtheye: Depends on whether `myString` is a sequence of multiple names & ids. Sure, `.match(/([a-z]+)(\d+)/i)` might be the better choice if not.

Comment: @Bergi Yup, that looks better.

Comment: I agreed  with Bergi and thefourtheye, here am using only single name and single id. so am going  to choose split().

Comment: @NoorFathima: No, we did recommend to use `match` for exactly that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it-

```
myString = "banana1212";
    var splits = myString.split(/(\d+)/);
    var prodName = splits[0];
    var prodId = splits[1];
alert(prodId);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D8L2J/2/

The result will be in a separate variable as you desired.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract numbers like this:

```
var myString = "banana12";
var val = /\d+/.exec(myString);
alert(val); // shows '12'
```

DEMO :http://jsfiddle.net/D8L2J/1/

Comment: Thank you,it is working what if i want characters in a separate variable.

Comment: @NoorFathima, could you share us an example of `separate variable` ? What you would like to acheive?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var myString = "banana1234";
var splits = myString.split(/(\d{1,})/);
    var prodName = splits[0];
    var prodId = splits[1];
alert(prodId);
```

fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/xYB2P/